# Custom jQuery form validation, hooks into additional checks

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm using jQuery to create my own validator (not using jQuery's own validator) where I want to make one validator work on many different forms without changing the code.

So my current validator gets bound on submit and checks through the fields. So it takes care of all the normal cases. If a form doesn't contain one of the validated fields, it ignores that field.

It works great, except for the rare case where a form has an extra field that will have some unique validation, I want to be able to add this to the PHP file itself, not the JS file where my standard validator is.

**What's the best way to extend my validator to add the custom validation checks?**
I need it integrated because I want all validation errors to be collected first, then output one alert box that contains all errors, both from my standard validator and the custom extended validation added on each page separately.

For some context, I've included some code snippets, but mainly pseudocode:

**myvalidator.js:**

```
$('form[data-validator=custom]').live('submit', function(e) {
  // Then checks if the field exists and validates
  $('[data-validate]').each(function() {
        // Check each field that has data-validate="email" for example
  });

  // If there are errors, add error message to one variable
  // At the end of the validation, display one alert with all the collected errors
  if(errors > 0) {
        alert(error_string);
        return false;
  }
}
```

**form9312.html**

```
<form data-validator="custom">
  <input type="text" name="email" data-validate="email" /> <!-- standard validation -->
  <input type="text" name="blarg" data-validate-custom="blarg" /> <!-- needs custom -->
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Add custom validation here
  // How?
  function validate_blarg() {
        // If it passes validation, return true;
        // If it fails, return an error message: "Blarg must be 5 characters long."
  }
</script>
```

Thanks for any help you can offer.

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, you could have a data-method attribute with the name of the custom validation method.

You can see an example of this here: http://viralpatel.net/blogs/2009/01/calling-javascript-function-from-string.html

Personally, this is where I would use jQuery validate because that level of configuration is already built and there seems to be some re-inventing the wheel going on with your approach.  What are you looking to do that jQuery validate doesn't do?

Comment: I ended up using `window[myfuncname](args)` to call it, where my validator grabs "blarg" then calls it.